# iOS build on testflight is hide after sometime

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, testflight

I uploaded an iOS build on test flight, It shows me in processing state, but after sometime, when I click on another link (inside app store site) or refresh page, then It automatically hide from there and also I have got no notification from there or not any failure mail from their side. Any suggestion or ideas are highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I have seen a new bug with TestFlight every-time there is a change/update. Post it on Bug reporter would be the best you can do. Try logging out and logging in again.

Comment: might be metadata missing, like app icon, permissions in plist, so on..